# php page is not opening in /usr/local/

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu-13.10

I am new to the php,And i Am using php5 in ubuntu 13.10 along with apache 2.4.
I have kept my php code in `/usr/local/phpTest`.Also I have changed apache configuration by adding phpTest.conf file in the conf-available,So that when i open `http://hostname/phpTest`
rather then opening main page its opens whatever code written in `/usr/local/phpTest/index.php` file.

I have checked that php is installed properlly by putting `info.php` script in the `/var/www/`.it shows me expected output.

Is there any configuration that i need to change to make it working.Please someone help me on it.

thanks
Vinay

Comment: Why do you put PHP scripts in that folder? You should put it at `/var/www/` by default

Comment: I have installed it using make command in the source code.so it is by default kept in that folder.

Comment: If you build PHP (or other software) from source the binaries and other php-compiler files is placed in /usr/local/, but the php scripts should not be there. You can choose any folder for php scripts (usually /var/www/) setting it by apache configuration.

(are you sure apache loaded your file?)

Comment: there are probably many other files in `/usr/local/`, esp. in `/usr/local/bin/`. Not recommended to open that folder to public (a.k.a. Internet).

Answer (score 0):

Two entries are required to change the server root directory:

First being the directive for the document root:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local"
```

Second being the directory privileges:

```
<Directory "/usr/local"> 
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride all 
  Order allow,deny 
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart apache after changing the configuration.

---

Though as mentioned in the comments it's probably not a good idea to do so, you should use VirtualHosts instead